# Build failure on Xcode 12.3,12.5 post updating react native version to 0.66.0

Tags: ios, reactjs, swift, react-native

Getting build failure while trying to compile my project post upgrading my react-native version to 0.66.0

My Podfile

```
require_relative './node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative './node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
platform :ios, '12.1'
use_frameworks!:linkage => :static

target 'ios-project' do
  
   config = use_native_modules!
   use_react_native!(
      :path => config[:reactNativePath],
      # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
      :hermes_enabled => false
    )
end
```

Compile error

```
/Users/xx/.bash_profile: line 4: export: `-s': not a valid identifier
/Users/xx/.bash_profile: line 4: export: `/nvm.sh': not a valid identifier
/Users/xx/.bash_profile: line 4: export: `]': not a valid identifier
N/A: version "N/A -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install N/A" to install it before using it.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Tried the following items but nothing worked for me

1. cleaning node_modules, podfiles.
2. node version 12.18.3
3. pods for 0.66.0 were successfully installed
4. tried on different XCode versions (12.3, 12.5, 13.0)
5. tried everything mentioned in this issue - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31733